# Run line in Rmd code chunk in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

How can I run a single (not selected) line in an Rmd code chunk in RStudio 1.0.143 (windows 7)? This worked on previous versions of RStudio. For example, keyboard shortcut ctr+enter works for a selection, but not for the active line.

Comment: `ctrl + enter` when there is no selection will run the line where the cursor is.

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do. it works with .R files but not .Rmd files in RStudio 1.0.143

Comment: It works for me even on .Rmd code chunks. My RStudio is version 1.0.136

Comment: It's working for me now. My code chunks were indented by 8 spaces, which knitted just fine, but was not recognized as a code chunk by R Studio. Apparently ctrl + enter only works inside a code chunk recognized by R Studio as a code chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the current active line of an .Rmd code chunk, use the shortcut `ctrl + enter` or `ctrl + r`. The code chunk must be recognized as a code chunk by R Studio.

Comment: are you suggesting a solution for a code chucnk in an *.Rmd file in RStudio?

Comment: Yes, if you have the cursor on a line in a .Rmd code chunk and press `ctrl + r` it will execute just that line.  It does for me anyway.

Comment: One feature that I turn off is Options -> R Markdown, and uncheck the box for "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents" so that the result displays in the console and not in the source code window.

Comment: What version R studio are you using? ctrl + r only works for me when text is highlighted; otherwise it does nothing. Same for ctrl + enter. I unchecked the box for "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents" but no change in behavior.

Comment: That's weird, it works for me.  What's even more weird, is when I look up all active shortcuts, `ctrl + r` isn't even listed in Rstudio's shortcuts (when looking within RStudios active shortcuts).  Now I'm confused. I'm using Rstudio 1.0.136 on Windows 7.